# In heroku db:push, what does "Resetting sequences" mean

Tags: heroku

Does it have something to do with the auto incremented IDs in tables?

Comment: Probably: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is a way to pass sequences up to heroku?

Comment: Not sure what mean, `db:push` should be taking care of that.

Comment: Strangely, it pushes the sequences for the model tables but not the link tables - which is a serious pain :(